# Voice recognition already running

Tags: javascript, webkit, speech-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

I use this speech recognition function to activate listening following a specific event, such as the end of an animation. Subsequently, it awaits user input and, based on the extracted speech, sends a request to the server. However, when the user remains silent, it triggers a `no-speech` error

My attempt to stop and restart the recognition process resulted in an error message: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started.`

How can I configure the system to continue listening until at least some speech is successfully extracted?

Code:

```
const recognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition)();
recognition.continuous = true;

function startRecognition() {
  recognition.onresult = async (event) => {
    const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    const intent = await extractIntent(transcript);
    console.log('Recognized speech:', transcript);
    console.log('Recognized intent:', intent);

    const payload = {
      ...
    }

    await fetch(awsUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    });
  };

  // Event listener for errors
  recognition.onerror = (event) => {
    console.error('Speech recognition error:', event.error);
    recognition.stop();
    startRecognition();
  };

  recognition.onnomatch = () => {
    console.log("Speech not recognized, trying again...");
    recognition.stop();
    startRecognition();
  };

  // Start recognition after everything is set up
  console.log('Listening...');
  recognition.start();
}
```